# How can I select the second last item in a xpath query?

Tags: xpath

I'm new to xpath and I understand how to get a range of values in xpath:

```
/bookstore/book[position()>=2 and position()<=10]
```

but in my case, I need to get above 2 and one less then the total(so if there's 10 then I need 9, or if there's 5, I need up to the 4th spot). I'm applying my code to different pages and the number of entries is not always the same.

In python, I could do something like book[2:-2], but I'm unsure if I can do this within xpath.

Comment: `/bookstore/book[position()>=2 and position() <= (last() - 1)]`

Comment: @helderdarocha WORKED!!! Can you do me a favour and put it as a answer so I can accept it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `last()` which represents the last item in the context:

```
/bookstore/book[position()>=2 and position() <= (last() - 1)]
```

Comment: thanks, tried it again and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: unable to fetch using this method

Comment: Should it be `/bookstore/book[position() = (last() - 1)]` ? Because this accepted answer does include every node between index 2 and N - 1, and not just the second last one.

Answer (score 6):

In my case this was working for me to get last but one element

```
/bookstore/book[position() = (last() - 1)]
```